# What is the equivalent of clFinish in opencl c++ API wrapper?

Tags: c++, opencl

I am new to opencl, but I am not new to GPU programming. I need to make sure that my cpu and gpu devices are synchronized with each other. It seems that I should use `clFinish(cl::commandqueue queue)`, but I am using opencl c++ not opencl c.

So, is `cl::finish()` the equivalent of `clFinish()` or is there something else like `cl::commandqueue::finish()` (which visual studio dose not recognize)?

Can you pleaes provide your answers with example? I am new to opencl.

Comment: Have you tried to check the documentation for opencl? Also, I assume the sources for **open**cl are available for download. I find source code to be the best documentation.

Answer (score 1):

`cl::command_queue::finish` is the one you are looking for.

```
cl_int finish() const
{
    return detail::errHandler(::clFinish(object_), __FINISH_ERR);
}
```

`cl::finish` gets the default queue and performs finish on that queue.

```
inline cl_int finish(void)
{
    cl_int error;
    CommandQueue queue = CommandQueue::getDefault(&error);

    if (error != CL_SUCCESS) {
        return error;
    } 


    return queue.finish();
}
```